# How to sync photos between the desktop and Picasa Web / Google Plus?

Tags: sync, photos, picasa, google-plus, picasa-web

I'm looking for some tool that can allow automatic bi-directional syncing between Picasa Web / Google Plus and a desktop photos folder.

The use case is of alternating between managing photos locally and online, so that if I e.g. decide to delete a crappy photo using the web site, the deletion propagates to the desktop.

I'm open for all directions, e.g. it could have been great if there was some tool that allowed mounting the Picasa Web albums locally (analogous to say [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) for Amazon S3) so that I can use rsync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the Picasa application (not the PicasaWeb webapp) is designed to do exactly that: http://picasa.google.com/

Comment: [Google Fotos](https://photos.google.com) (the successor of Picasa) does this by default. When you delete a picture using the webinterface it is deleted on your smartphone too. The other way also works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with the Picasa application. When downloaded and installed use "import photos from google+" functionality. After doing so you can sync both the downloaded folder and the one on google+. Local edits wont be synced though. I recommended to have the sync set on just temporarily. I summed up my findings here, I hope this helps:
http://www.trip.me/blog/moving-photos-picasa-google-plus/